# NSubstitute ReceivedCallsException error when run calls in a sequence

Tags: xunit, nsubstitute

When I run below tests in below sequence ((i.e. Test1 and then Test2) it throws the mentioned error. But it works fine if it runs opposite sequence. (i.e. Test2 and then Test1)

[Fact]

```
public async Task Test1()
{
    var body = GenerateStreamFromString();
    var rawMessage = new BrokeredMessage(body);

    ProductContractIngestFunc.GetProductContractDataHandler = log => Task.FromResult(_dataHandler);

    await ProductContractIngestFunc.Ingest(rawMessage, _logger);

    await _feedbackService.DidNotReceiveWithAnyArgs().ReportIssueAsync(
        Arg.Any<BrokeredMessage>(),
        Arg.Any<DataSyncValidationException>());
}

[Fact]
public async Task Test2()
{
    var body = GenerateStreamFromString();
    var rawMessage = new BrokeredMessage(body);

    var mockFeatureFlagService = Substitute.For<IFeatureFlagService>();
    var featureFlag = new FeatureFlag { Enabled = false };

    mockFeatureFlagService.GetFeatureFlagAsync(ApplicationConstant.SyncDataType.ProductContract)
        .Returns(Task.FromResult(featureFlag));

    ServiceInjector.GetFeedbackService = log => _feedbackService;
    ServiceInjector.GetFeatureFlagService = log => mockFeatureFlagService;

    await ProductContractIngestFunc.Ingest(rawMessage, _logger);

    await _feedbackService.ReceivedWithAnyArgs().ReportIssueAsync(
        Arg.Any<BrokeredMessage>(),
        Arg.Any<FeatureFlagException>());

}
```

Below error occurs in `_feedbackService.ReceivedWithAnyArgs()`

Error :

```
at NSubstitute.Core.ReceivedCallsExceptionThrower.Throw(ICallSpecification callSpecification, IEnumerable`1 matchingCalls, IEnumerable`1 nonMatchingCalls, Quantity requiredQuantity)
   at NSubstitute.Routing.Handlers.CheckReceivedCallsHandler.Handle(ICall call)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectArrayIterator`2.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.FirstOrDefault[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 predicate)
   at NSubstitute.Routing.Route.Handle(ICall call)
   at NSubstitute.Proxies.CastleDynamicProxy.CastleForwardingInterceptor.Intercept(IInvocation invocation)
   at Castle.DynamicProxy.AbstractInvocation.Proceed()
```

Initially I thought it's because of the sharing same object and then trying to reset the mock objects in each tests still no difference.

Comment: Maybe try adding [NSubstitute.Analyzers](http://nsubstitute.github.io/help/nsubstitute-analysers/) to your test project and see if it picks up any problems with non-virtual members?

Comment: @DavidTchepak Can you please shed more light on how to setup Nsubstitute Analyzer, like creation of `nsubstitute.json`. I went through`https://github.com/nsubstitute/NSubstitute.Analyzers/blob/dev/documentation/Configuration.md` couldn't figure out

Comment: You don't need an `nsubstitute.json` unless you want to set up specific rule exclusions. All that is generally required is referencing the package. If you need exclusions please [create an issue](https://github.com/nsubstitute/NSubstitute.Analyzers/issues) describing the error you are getting adding the file.

Comment: @DavidTchepak After further investigation we found out that it's a implementation issue unfortunately. The reason being we have mocked one of the services that shouldn't have. `_dataHandler` in above

Comment: Glad you got it sorted @SMPH, thanks for letting me know.